# Event Emmiter returns error 500 with express.js, it only gets 200 response over one event

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, eventemitter

On my project I have some sore of function that emmits some events:

```
const express = require('express');
const EventEmitter = require('events');

/*Initialize Body parsers etc etc*/

const emmiter=new EventEmitter();

const emmitFunctionality=function(message){
  if(message==='hello'){
   return emmiter.emit("ok")
  }
  return emmiter.emit("fail");
}

express.post('/my-route',function(req,res,next){

   emmiter.on('ok',function(){
     res.json({status:true})
   });

   emmiter.on('fail',function(){
     res.json({status:fail})
   });

   emmitFunctionality(req.message);
})

app.listen(80,function(){
  console.log("Listening over port: 80");
});
```

But I have a problem when I try do the following http `POST` request works fine:

> POST http://localhost/my-route -d "{message:'hello'}"

Whilst I try to do

> POST http://localhost/my-route -d "{message:'harem'}"

I get the following response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:503:11)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:510:3)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at ServerResponse.header (/opt/map/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at ServerResponse.send (/opt/map/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at ServerResponse.json (/opt/map/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at EventEmitter.emmiter.on (/opt/map/src/controllers/panel.js:42:9)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:164:20)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at module.exports.self.readAllLinesFromXLSXBufferAndProcessWithACallback (/opt/map/src/services/excell.js:41:20)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /opt/map/src/controllers/panel.js:46:16<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/map/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Do you fellows know the reason why that happens and how I will solve it?

Comment: You should `return emmiter.emmit("fail");` too.

Comment: This code would never run, there is no such function as .emmit. Did you mean .emit? If this isn't a more or less exact copy/paste of the problematic code, odds are you haven't reproduced the actual problem code.

Comment: Fixed the bug you noticed thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the response has sent the headers. This can be done via the following piece of code:

```
if(!res.headersSent) {
  //send response here
}
```

So over your code the section resulting into the post over the `/my-route` route will be:

```
express.post('/my-route',function(req,res,next){

   emmiter.on('ok',function(){
     if(!res.headersSent) {
       res.json({status:true})
     }
   });

   emmiter.on('fail',function(){
     if(!res.headersSent) {
      res.json({status:fail})
     }
   });
 emmitFunctionality(req.message);
})
```

Comment: This is really not a good design decision. You should not use `EventEmitter` at all. Also this will produce `MaxListenersExceededWarning` after 10-15 requests has been made.